# Delete MySQL row from JQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Good Day!
I'm trying to delete a row in a MySQL database, via PHP, with an AJAX request.
I thought it was easy with `$.ajax {}`but for some reasons, no row isn't deleted...
I have this script (with jQuery):

```
function deleteRecord(i) {

    console.log("Line to delete: " + i);
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"../php/delete.php",
        data: { delete : i },
        success:function(data){
            console.log("Line deleted from the database.");
            $("#results").empty();
            showWholeDB();
        }
    });
}
```

and in the PHP side:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $sql = "DELETE id FROM table1 WHERE id=".$_POST['delete'];

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "myDB");
    if (!$con) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_error($con));
    }

    mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

In the console log I see the messages:

> Line to delete: 215

(the line I want to delete)
and :

> Line deleted from the database.

Then the frame empties and the database is loaded again, but my line is still here!
I used this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623997/deleting-mysql-table-row-with-jquery-ajax).
I'm not sure if I missed something but it's not working... 
Can somebody help me, please ?
Thank You very much in advance! :)

Comment: try to debug using `print_r()` and `die`. You will understand why your code is not executing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting mySQL Table Row with jQuery Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623997/deleting-mysql-table-row-with-jquery-ajax)

Comment: You should use `DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id=".intval($_POST['delete']);` to prevent SQL injection hacking attacks.

Comment: @Adder how does that prevent sql injections?

Comment: use the `jquery ajax error function` to confirm whether its going to the correct path or not..

Comment: @Masivuye Cokile It changes any attack code to an integer, for example zero, so at worst the code tries to delete the entry with id zero which probably doesn't even exist.

Comment: @Eric Your Delete query syntax should be

DELETE  FROM table1 WHERE id=2
Try to use prepared statement like my below answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$sql = "DELETE id FROM table1 WHERE id=".intval($_POST['delete']);
```

TO

```
 $sql = "DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id=".intval($_POST['delete']);
```

Comment: You are promoting code that is vulnerable to big sql injections. Please reconsider.

Comment: @SimosFasouliotis I just show the mistake in query what was the issue with that?

Comment: Just change the code to use `intval($_POST['delete'])` and it will be protected against SQL injection.

Comment: @Adder Thanks. :)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It works! Thanks a lot for the help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Your Delete query syntax should be

```
DELETE  FROM table1 WHERE id=2
```

Try to use prepared statement like this .

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "myDB") or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

$stmt = $con->prepare("DELETE  FROM table1 WHERE id=?");

$stmt->bind_param('i',$_POST['delete']);

//The argument may be one of four types:

//i - integer
//d - double
//s - string
//b - BLOB
//change it by respectively 

$stmt->execute();

$row_count= $stmt->affected_rows;

if($row_count>0)
{
   echo "Deleted";

}else{

  echo "Not Deleted";
}
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your delete query
DELETE FROM table_name [WHERE Clause]

Answer (score 0):

i think the "delete" parameter in ajax did not post the data to url that's why this is my running code

```
 Jquery :

   $.ajax({
    url: 'url',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        'user_id': id


    },
    success: function (res) {
        $('#user_'+id).slideUp(500);
    }
  });

PHP :
  mysql_query("DELETE FROM tblusers WHERE user_id = $user_id");
```

Comment: it's url that page you want to post data

Answer (score 0):

Your delete syntax is wrong, see [delete from documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html) And you should also use prepared statements in your php.

```
function deleteRecord(i) {

    console.log("Line to delete: " + i);
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"../php/delete.php",
        data: {delete : i },
        dataType : "json",
        encode : true,
        success:function(data){

           if(data == "ok"){
            console.log("Line deleted from the database.");
            $("#results").empty();
            showWholeDB();

           }else{
            console.log(data);
           }

        }
    });
}
</script>
```

**delete.php**

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}

if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {

    $idToDelete = intval($_POST['delete']);
    $sql        = "DELETE  FROM table1 WHERE id= ?";

    $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bin_param("i", $idToDelete);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        echo "ok";
    } else {

        echo "Error : " . $con->error;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is useful :)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $sql = "DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id=".$_POST['delete'];

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "myDB");
    if (!$con) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_error($con));
    }

    mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    mysqli_close($con);
}

?>
```